# bash. Запускать на выполнение php-скрипт в цикле, пока он не вернет false

Tags: php, bash

Ubuntu server.

Необходимо с помощью bash в цикле запускать на выполнение php-скрипт пока он (php-скрипт) возвращает true (или какое-то значение). Как только php-скрипт возвращает отличное от true значение - цикл завершить. Дополнительно ограничить количество итераций цикла 100 повторениями.

Подскажите как это сделать.

Comment: вместо "команда" запускаю sudo -u admin php "/home/web/.../script.php", который возвращает либо true, либо false. Если false - то прервать цикл.

Comment: php-скрипт по результату выполнения возвращает "return true;", либо "return false;". Это значение нужно отследить и соответственно либо продолжить цикл, либо прервать выполнение.

Comment: т.е., php не имеет **никакого** отношения к вопросу. внесите, пожалуйста, правку, убрав метки php, ubuntu, shell (раз вам именно на bash-е нужно решение, а не на posix-совместимой оболочке), и, очень желательно, упоминания (в тексте вопроса) всего того, что не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу («ubuntu-сервер», «php-скрипт» и т.п.), оставив только существенную информацию.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

eval.php:

```
<?php
if (time() % 20 === 0) {
    exit(1);
} else {
    exit(0);
}
```

runner.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in {1..100}
do
    php ./eval.php || break;
done
```

Добавил для примера, чтобы показать, что php-скрипт может возвращать разные статусы: НЕУСПЕХ - в случае запуска, когда текущее время содержит количество секунд равное 20, иначе - УСПЕХ.

Запускать `runner.sh`